# R Save plots to pdf file opened earlier

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I want to save a plot to my computer as a pdf but want to leave it open so I can add plots to it later, so I do this:

```
 pdf("~/Desktop/plots")
 plot(1:10)
```

I then create and save a new pdf:

```
 pdf("~/Desktop/plot1")
 plot(rnorm(10))
 dev.off()
```

But I don't know how to go back to that first pdf and add another plot to it? This doesn't work:

```
pdf("~/Desktop/plots")
plot(rnorm(10))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dev.off()` twice it will close first file too.

Comment: Interesting. This allows me to open plots.pdf. But It just contains the second plot (plot(rnorm(10))) and not the first one (plot(1:10)).